# LOCF (last observation carried forward) in Vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

I am trying to find pandas-style function LOCF in Vertica, I cound find last_value and first_value, but my data is not in their wanted format:

```
date myValue wanted
20171201 NA NA
20180101 10 10
20180102 NA 10
20180103 NA 10
20180105 4  4
20180106 6  6
20180108 NA 6
20180202 7  7
```

where I could use the first_value/last_value for LOCF if the data was in the format

```
date myValue myPartition 
20171201 NA 0
20180101 10 1
20180102 NA 1
20180103 NA 1
20180105 4  2
20180106 6  3
20180108 NA 3
20180202 7  4
```

for which I could use

```
SELECT date, myValue, 
  LAST_VALUE(myValue) OVER (PARTITION BY myPartition ORDER BY date ASC) AS wanted
FROM myDataAbove
```

where one approach would be to create the partition to use LAST_VALUE in order to implement LOCF function. Otherwise, we could try to find LOCF function directly for Vertica.

What is the most convenient way to implemnet LOCF for Vertica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just count the number of non-`'NA'` values up to each point:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when myvalue <> 'NA' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date) as myPartition
from t;
```

If the column is really stored as a number and `'NA'` is `NULL`, you'll need `NOT NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

- NULL instead of an 'NA' string
- the ANSI standard IGNORE NULLS directive for LAST_VALUE, and:
- Vertica's CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT() OLAP function for the change of `myvalue`...

Like so:

```
WITH input(dt, myvalue,wanted,mypartition) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2017-12-01',NULL::INT,NULL::INT,0 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-01',10       ,10       ,1 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-02',NULL::INT,10       ,1 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-03',NULL::INT,10       ,1 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-05',4        ,4        ,2 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-06',6        ,6        ,3 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-01-08',NULL::INT,6        ,3 
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2018-02-02',7        ,7        ,4 
)
SELECT
  dt
, myvalue
, LAST_VALUE(myvalue IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS val_gen
, wanted
, CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(myvalue IS NOT NULL) OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS part_gen
, mypartition
FROM input;

Output:
dt        |myvalue|val_gen|wanted|part_gen|mypartition
2017-12-01|(null) |(null) |(null)|       0|          0
2018-01-01|     10|     10|    10|       1|          1
2018-01-02|(null) |     10|    10|       1|          1
2018-01-03|(null) |     10|    10|       1|          1
2018-01-05|      4|      4|     4|       2|          2
2018-01-06|      6|      6|     6|       3|          3
2018-01-08|(null) |      6|     6|       3|          3
2018-02-02|      7|      7|     7|       4|          4
```